# Can my brother from Australia buy a flydubai airline ticket for me?

Tags: tickets, airlines, bangladeshi-citizens, flydubai

I live in Dubai and plan to visit my country next year. I don't have credit card here and I want to buy flydubai tickets. Also I am from Bangladesh.

Can my brother from Australia buy a ticket from his credit card?

Comment: what is your nationality?

Comment: I am from Bangladesh

Comment: I am not sure if FlyDubai is a member of IATA, but if so, then your brother should be able to book through an IATA travel agency and pay by whatever means the agency accepts.  The FlyDubai rules being discussed refer primarily to online bookings.

Comment: @Tom I have used flydubai twice, system automatically detect nationals who need to provide credit card. On my ticket it was written underneath that credit card will be checked at the airport. His brother can buy ticket from flydubai or any other online resources but again when he will get stuck at the airport , he will still need to provide credit card. Therefore it is better not to use others credit card when buying ticket from flydubai :)

Comment: @AliAwan - Travel agency bookings are treated differently than online bookings, because in practice the customer buying the ticket appears before the travel agent and the form of payment is verified. Online bookings fall under different rules because the card / cardholder is not physically present at booking time to be verified, hence online bookings sometimes require additional verification at check in.

Comment: @Tom IATA says flydubai is IATA member: [IATA](http://www.iata.org/about/members/Pages/airline-list.aspx?All=true)

Comment: @AliAwan - Then in theory you should be able to book a ticket on FlyDubai through a travel agent.

Comment: @Tom interesting, you can also post this as a new answer:)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Can my brother from Australia buy a ticket from his credit card?

NO, your brother cannot buy an airline ticket from his credit card on your behalf. Bangladesh is listed on those countries which cannot use a credit/debit card to pay for someone else.

Source:[flydubai](https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/ways-to-pay)

**Pay on someone else's behalf**

You can pay for another traveller's flight using cash. Just select the 'pay later' option when you book, then make the payment through one of our Payment Partners. If you want to pay by credit/debit card, the person you’re paying for will need to show a photocopy of the front of your credit/debit card and a photocopy of your passport at check-in. You can't use your credit/debit card to pay for someone else to travel to or from **Bangladesh, Ethiopia, Nepal, Pakistan, Sri Lanka or Sudan.**

However there is also a possiblity to reserve a seat and select 'pay later' when you book through online or through customer service and pay at a flydubai Travel Shop or through one of their Payment Partners (a payment fee may apply).

Source:[flydubai](https://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/ways-to-pay)

[image]

Comment: Is this true for all airlines ? I would have thought a true certified copy of used credit/debit card would suffice mostly

Comment: no not all airlines, OP is just asking for flydubai and conditions are only for certain countries not for all nationals. every airline has different policy

Comment: I will start a bounty when I can (and delete this comment then): this answer is spectacular, reflects rare, specific knowledge and is properly sourced. I would've never thought the answer could be no.

Answer (score 8):

As FlyDubai is a IATA member airline, your brother maybe able to book a ticket for you through a travel agency in Australia and pay for that ticket with whatever form of payment the agency accepts.

Folks are so used to doing everything online, they have forgotten about the old fashion way of doing bookings face to face either at the airline's ticket office or an IATA appointed travel agency.  In person bookings fall under different rules when it comes to verification of form of payment.  In practice a customer booking a ticket in person appears before the travel agent, produces the form of payment be it a credit card or check or other such and thus those bookings are considered as FOP verified (form of payment).

With an online booking neither the card nor the cardholder are physically present for verification, thus that sale is more open to fraud.  Hence a number of airlines require showing the card at check in to verify its validity and your permission to have charged to it.  And in the OP's specific case, obviously a number of countries have been sources of frequent credit card fraud, thus are no longer allowed able to avail themselves to 3rd party card payments.

Another possible alternative would be for your brother to wire funds to cover the ticket cost and you walk into a FlyDubai ticket office to purchase your ticket with cash.

Comment: +1 and turning out to be an interesting question. Still looking for a reliable source so that OP would be OK at the airport

Comment: Are we confident it's flydubai that is the source of the restriction related to credit cards and others, and not national laws/regulations?

Comment: @Joe - If every airline and online business in Dubai had the same rules, then perhaps it could be national laws, but otherwise it will company policy.

Answer (score 1):

Yes he can, flydubai has visa/master card verification, your brother must send you a photocopy of his passport and credit card.

Good to go.